# Use C++ possibilities in C

Tags: c

It might be a silly question, but I'm interested in it very much. Is it possible to implement operator `new`, dynamically expanding arrays, classes in pure C? 
Any links or code examples will be appreciated.

Comment: The subject is way too broad, but check this free book which is exactly about OOP in C: http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf

Comment: @ddriver, thanks for the link. Really useful one.

Comment: Obviously you *can* do those things in C, because Stoustrop's first C++ compilers output C. But it's a lot of work.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker - back then C++ had a miniscule fraction of the features it has today. So it shouldn't be all that much work, especially if you write a codegen instead of writing it all in place by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `new`: `#define new(type) malloc(sizeof(type))` (have to call it using function syntax, like `struct stat *st = new(struct stat)`)
- dynamically expanding arrays: `realloc` plus some custom array-manipulation functions (like `push_back`, etc.) - this is commonly implemented by third-party C utility libraries (and, as @Mgetz points out, some compilers have built-in extensions for it)
- classes: structs with function pointer members (this is very common in several projects, such as the Linux kernel)

You might want to look at GObject, which is a C library providing some object-oriented features to C.  Also see the dozens of hits you get for googling "Object-Oriented C".

Comment: gcc actually had their own [`VEC_` macros](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/gcc-4_3-branch/gcc/vec.h) that did much of what the OP is asking for. Although those are being phased out with the c++ conversion.

Comment: If the user is going to define a `new` macro that should most likely be done in a `#ifndef __cplusplus` guard

Comment: @ddriver not should most likely, MUST be done in such a block. As redefining keywords is a compile error in C++

Comment: @Mgetz: assuming the OP wants to interoperate with C++ code at all. Remember that C and C++ are distinct languages that happen to share a common origin.

Comment: and thus the "should most likely" instead of "must"

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search revealed this:
http://ooc-coding.sourceforge.net/

Haven't read it through but it sounds like what you're after.

Yes, it is possible (common?) to implement object orientedness in C - or at least the bits that are especially needed.

An example is a once created a garbage collector by storing the pointers to malloced memory and the free function in linked lists.

The best thing about C is that it just works and there is almost zero overhead. The more work a language does for you automatically *can* mean there is a lot more overhead - though this is not always the case.

Answer (score -1):

It depends if it is OK for you to reimplement the compiler.
If it's ok - you can do whatever you wish, otherwise:

new - as an operator - no, but you can define a function + macros that will simulate it.
classes - yep, you can. you may simulate it pretty closely with static functions and an array of pointers to functions. But there will be no overloading.
expanding arrays - yes, with the classes simulation above.

Comment: It is not at all `reimplementing the compiler`---rather a tiny subset of it ! Also,it'll make OP understand the other workings! Don't give others false impressions of things which are absurd!!!

Comment: @shekharsuman if it's absurd for you - it doesn't mean it is for everybody. Of course, i didn't mean to rebuild it from scratch - but you can rather implement some features in the compiler code or use utils, such as [codeworker](http://codeworker.free.fr/) or others